# Open file from phones memory onClick in android

Tags: android

I am creating and storing CSV and XML files in my application. Whenever I want to check the data of these files I have to go to my phones memory and open the particular file. Is it possible to open the particular file from my app itself by clicking the particular files name button?

Comment: you mean from your app? or other file apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can open file with openFileInput (for read file):

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then you can read this file with read() function.
Close file at the end:

```
fis.close().
```